# css transform translate doesn't work on y axis

Tags: html, css, transform, translate

I want to centralize a `div` block on both x-axis and y-axis. But I can't move the block by using `translate`.

```css
.maincontain {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.bannerimage {
  position: absolute;
  width: 64%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="maincontain">
  <div class="bannerimage" id="image_gallery">
    <img src="./img/2.jpg" alt="2">
    <img src="./img/3.jpg" alt="3">
    <img src="./img/4.jpg" alt="4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.maincontain { min-height: 100%;}` requires a parent with an height set to be efficient *(% need a value from the parent to be calculated here ;) )*, do you have it in your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using `flex` or `grid` to avoid playing around with `position`, `min-height` can also use `vh` units (viewport height) instead % that requires to inherit an height value from the parent to calculate it.

examples:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.maincontain {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.bannerimage {
  margin: auto;
  width: 64%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="maincontain">
  <div class="bannerimage" id="image_gallery">
    <img src="./img/2.jpg" alt="2">
    <img src="./img/3.jpg" alt="3">
    <img src="./img/4.jpg" alt="4">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.maincontain {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.bannerimage {
  margin: auto;
  width: 64%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="maincontain">
  <div class="bannerimage" id="image_gallery">
    <img src="./img/2.jpg" alt="2">
    <img src="./img/3.jpg" alt="3">
    <img src="./img/4.jpg" alt="4">
  </div>
</div>
```